# Default angular project template from Visual Studio fails with exception unhandled on first run

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I just created a new asp.net core app with an angular template and when I started it I received an exception

> - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference

on this line

```
function combine(options) {
   return ((Object)).assign.apply(((Object)), [{}].concat(options));}
```

in the vendor.js file

anybody know why or how to fix it? Should I have an exception thrown on a default project template like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using VS Angular template, as it doesn't provide best experience for Angular app setup.You can follow steps in this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) or create empty ASP.NET Web API project, install Node.js & Angular-Cli. Then you can run 'npm i npm' and 'ng new myAppName' in project's root directory.